# Composed annotation using spring meta annotation not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

Am trying to create a Composed annotation using spring meta annotation @Mapping.

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Mapping
public @interface RestQuery {
    RequestMethod[] method() default {RequestMethod.GET};
    String[] produces() default {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE};
    String[] consumes() default {""};
    String[] value() default {};
    String[] params() default {};

}

@Controller
public class CustomerQueryController{
    @RestQuery(value="/test")
    public String test(){
        return "test";
    }
}
```

When I annotate a spring controller method using the above annotation, I get an exception that the URI is not mapped. Any ideas, where I am going wrong?

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound            | No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/test/] in DispatcherServlet with name ''
```

Comment: I have no idea why you use `@Mapping`.  Spring MVC only resolves `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: If you have a look at the source RequestMapping is composed from Mapping. I tried using RequestMapping and it doesn't work at the class level. Will update the question?

Comment: What do you mean by `@RequestMapping` doesn't work at the class level?

Comment: Based on your earlier comment, I implemented `@RestQuery` composing from `@RequestMapping` instead of `@Mapping`. The new annotation `@RestQuery` works when applied to methods, but does not work when applied to a class.